# Windows Form con transparencia y degradado

Tags: c#, vb.net, windows-forms

Inicialmente necesitaba hacer que un formulario tenga un area a la que pueda ser transparente y pueda interactuar con esa area tal que así

```html
Public Class Form1
    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()
        Me.BackColor = Color.Blue
        Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Blue
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)
        DrawGradientWithTransparency(e.Graphics)
    End Sub
    Private Sub DrawGradientWithTransparency(ByVal g As Graphics)
        Dim rect As New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)
        Dim transparentColor As Color = Color.FromArgb(0, Color.Red)
        Using brush As New SolidBrush(transparentColor)
            g.FillRectangle(brush, rect)
        End Using
    End Sub
End class
```

Con esto estoy logrando pintar el formulario transparente pero adicionalmente puedo mantener los eventos sobre el formulario y no sobre los objetos de fondo.
Ahora lo que deseo hacer es pintar un gradiente de color que inicie con un color solido y finalice con un transparente total y las soluciones en internet que he encontrado hasta ahora lo que me da es una transparencia pero como si el formulario tuviera un fondo blanco. no tengo mas opción que usar Windows Form pero aun así puedo usar C# o VB.net.
El objetivo final es simular la sombra que proyecta un formulario sobre cualquier cosa que este detrás del formulario a sus bordes, mismos que sirven para redimensionar.
ya solo em falta eso, luego presento el resultado final de un formulario sin barra de menu.
PD. con lograr el gradiente de color con transparencia le resto de ajustes lo hago yo, porque hasta ahora eso es lo mas difícil.
PD2. Creo que se me ocurrió una idea y probare con imágenes sobre el formulario, el problema va a ser si gasta mas recursos de los esperados al mover el formulario. (Resulta que Me.TransparencyKey = Color.Blue) la imagen de fondo en el picture box los degradados se hacen sobre ese color "transparente" definido en  Me.TransparencyKey que para este caso es el azul

Comment: No entiendo bien el resultado final, sería bueno que pusieras una imagen del resultado esperado

Comment: Tal cual una ventana con su sombra, o también al abrir illustrator cc, se puede ver eso mismo de transparencias

Comment: Mi avance, mas después subo ya como una pregunta y respuesta aqui. https://github.com/StringCGE/FormSinBordes

Comment: @StringGCE así es no hay transparencia real en winforms. Sólo un color sobre el cual dibuja lo que hay detrás del form. Al haber miles de colores entre los 2 colores del degradado que el sistema rellena, nuestro ojo lo percibe como un azul que se desvanece. Pero para el sistema tan solo subirle 1 "punto de rojo" ya es otro color diferente y no lo considera como trasnparetKey sobre el cual pintar la transparencia simulada. Te sugiero que uses WPF que también usa C#.

Comment: Si de todas formas quieres hacerlo en winforms tal vez puedas echarle un vistazo a la segunda parte de esta respuesta [Apply the opacity of a LinearGradientBrush to an image in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40719580/16270137). Donde pone un código que me parece que edita pixel a pixel el fondo. Tal vez encuentres ahí lo que buscas.